# Enabled the anonymous access for entire site collection but getting access denied on list /libraries

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, anonymous-authentication

I am using a Team Site template with Publishing feature Enabled. When user is trying to access the homepage, it is working as expected.

But when they trying to access any List / Libraries they simply prompt for loging or access denied. I don't know why?

I make sure, all pages are approve & published, also add anonymous access on all system libraries.

anything i am missing? I am SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/07/16/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-to-your-sharepoint-site/

Comment: Look at the comments as well. The mod is stating that if you wanna restrict access to list and site content, then activate the publishing feature. Might help you out to deactivate it?

Comment: i already performed those steps but still no luck.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2012/01/13/can-t-access-a-list-on-an-anonymous-site-sharepoint-2010.aspx Check this out then, i still believe it got something to do with the publishing feature.

Comment: i think you are correct, i overlooked that part, i thought its team site so i dont need to worry even publishing feature....I was wrong...Thanks alot....solve the issue....Could you please add this as answer so that i can mark and give you points.

Comment: Glad to hear that i could help. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When giving anonymous access to a publishing portal or a site with the publishing feature activate, there is an additional feature getting activated called ViewFormPagesLockdown. This feature prevents anonymous users from gaining access to certain areas of a site. That includes list forms.

From the blog:

> This feature still exists in SharePoint 2010 and is still automatically turned on for Publishing Portal sites. This feature is referred to as lockdown mode and can be turned on or off by enabling/disabling the ViewFormPagesLockdown feature.

[Lockdown Mode in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/01/22/lockdown-mode-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

An additional good blogpost about why you should handle this feature with care.

[Login prompt accessing list on SharePoint site with anonymous access enabled](http://khalidansari.com/2014/01/17/login-prompt-accessing-list-on-sharepoint-site-with-anonymous-access-enabled/)

Comment: fantastic catch