# anonymous access in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, permissions, anonymous-authentication

i am new at sharepoint administration, so my question should be simple enough for the experts.
i have a sharepoint Site done everything in it and works fine with windows authentication, now i extended the web application for **internet** access with *anonymous access*, no login required and i stopped the windows authentication from the IIS for the extended site.
now everything almost works fine but some images and styles are not appearing in the extended web application (the anonymous site) and still works fine on the original site under windows authentication.
i went to the library and fixed the permission to be inherited from the top site.
but still no luck, any ideas????

> i found the image is an SharePoint:SiteLogoImage and the url is not absolute.

Comment: Where are the images or styles loading from?

Comment: Are you using publishing infrastructure on the site? There is a default feature that may prevent some files to be reached. You should use F12 to see what urls that are not loading and check the permission there. My guess is that the style library is the problem. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105317/enabled-the-anonymous-access-for-entire-site-collection-but-getting-access-denie/105318#105318

Comment: yes i am using publishing infrastructure,and the library called "Style Library". the image could be viewed using the site on the authenticated port but not with the link with no authenticated needed,on F12 i found there is inline style wrote that does not appear in anonymous access .

Answer (score 1):

Usually for resources in the Style Library, they must be published before normal or anonymous users can see them. Through your browser, on your windows authentication site, go to Site Contents and then your Style Library. Find the items that are not appearing for anonymous users, check them out, and when you check them back in make sure you choose to publish a major version.

Also, check where you are referencing the resources and make sure you are using relative URLs and not absolute URLs. If you use absolute URLs, which contain your windows authentication site URL as a part of the path, then your anonymous users won't be able to access those resources.